# How to Replace some part of TextView's text with an image and get co-ordinates of that image?

Tags: android, android-widget

[image]

I am writing a drag and drop code. the requirement is i drag an answer and drop it in the space provided(Fill in the blank). what i am thinking is i drag a view over screen and match the coordinates of space provided and release the view i.e on Action_Up. Now the problem is the space for fill up will be set at run time I.e. a string with "[WOL]" text i have to replace this text with a fill up image and get the co-ordinates of image to match the dragged view. pls help me how to accomplish this. pls check the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace part of TextView with an image, or another component...

From the screenshot above, I can see 3 separate components:
1. a `TextView` ("*The calories were high for each*"),
2. an `EditText` (or ImageView, whatever is that component)
3. and another `TextView` ("*serving*");

Comment: Actually you can replace part of text with image. Using Html.ImageGetter check this :-)

Comment: I didn't take the HTML version in consideration, Thanks for letting me know that :)